# NopCommerce Plugin Uninstall

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm currently developing a plugin to add a banner to specific pages, where i am using NopCommerces, official guide on how to develop a plugin. However when I carried out an uninstall and a reinstall of the plugin, I still have access to my old images. As the uninstall has only dropped certain data in the database but not the images or the picture IDs that have been set in the service. What would be the best way to remove the data from the service.

```
   public void Uninstall()
    {
        var dbScript = "Select * into[temp"+ now.Year+"] FROM [Temp]"; //BackUP
        var dbScript = "DROP TABLE Temp";
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbScript);
        SaveChanges();
    }
```